# Where are changes made by swap?

Tags: c++, swap

This code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void swap(unsigned char& a, unsigned char& b)
{
    unsigned char t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned bgr = 0x0000FF;
    swap(((unsigned char*) &bgr)[0], ((unsigned char*) &bgr)[2]);
    printf("0x%06X\n", bgr);
}
```

output:

0x0000FF

Where are changes made by swap ?

Comment: Read about [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: @juanchopanza: References and no return statement in main. Doesn't look like C to me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're right. I got confused by the arguments to `swap` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to modify `bgr`. `bgr` is `const`. Modifying a `const` variable is *undefined behaviour*. This can manifest itself in many ways, and you cannot rely on any specific behaviour. A good way to figure out what is happening on your platform is to look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: What's the reason to modifying a const be undefined behavior instead of forbidden behavior?

Comment: @user3123061 making it undefined gives the compiler some leeway to do whatever it sees fit. In order to be forbidden, the compiler would have to be able to detect all the different possibilities which is somewhere between hard and impossible.

Answer (score 3):

`bgr` is `const` in this case.  My guess is that you're invoking undefined behavior by attempting to swap it's first and last byte.  Removing the `const` results in an actual swap on my platform:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void swap(unsigned char& a, unsigned char& b)
{
    unsigned char t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned bgr = 0x0000FF;
    swap(((unsigned char*) &bgr)[0], ((unsigned char*) &bgr)[2]);
    printf("0x%06X\n", bgr);
}
```

Now compile and run:

```
$ g++ -Wall foo.cpp ; ./a.out 
0xFF0000
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you declared `bgr` to be `const`, you've fallen victim to a compiler optimization. Rather than passing the actual variable to `printf`, it passed a constant value.

If the variable had not been declared `const` the optimization wouldn't have been made.